# How could an assembly OUTB function cause a triple fault?

Tags: operating-system, x86, interrupt, hobby-os

In my systems programming class we are working on a small, simple hobby OS. Personally I have been working on an ATA hard disk driver. I have discovered that a single line of code seems to cause a fault which then immediately reboots the system. The code in question is at the end of my interrupt service routine for the IDE interrupts. Since I was using the IDE channels, they are sent through the slave PIC (which is cascaded through the master). Originally my code was only sending the end-of-interrupt byte to the slave, but then my professor told me that I should be sending it to the master PIC as well.

SO here is my problem, when I un-comment the line which sends the EOI byte to the master PIC, the systems triple faults and then reboots. Likewise, if I leave it commented the system stays running.

```
_outb( PIC_MASTER_CMD_PORT, PIC_EOI );  // this causes (or at least sets off) a triple fault reboot
_outb( PIC_SLAVE_CMD_PORT, PIC_EOI );
```

Without seeing the rest of the system, is it possible for someone to explain what could possibly be happening here?

NOTE: Just as a shot in the dark, I replaced the _outb() call with another _outb() call which just made sure that the interrupts were enable for the IDE controller, however, the generated assembly would have been almost identical. This did not cause a fault.

*_outb() is a wrapper for the x86 OUTB instruction.

What is so special about my function to send EOI to the master PIC that is an issue?

I realize without seeing the code this may be impossible to answer, but thanks for looking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triple faults usually point to a stack overflow or odd stack pointer. When a fault or interrupt occurs, the system immediately tries to push some more junk onto the stack (before invoking the fault handler). If the stack is hosed, this will cause another fault, which then tries to push more stuff on the stack, which causes another fault. At this point, the system gives up on you and reboots.

I know this because I actually have a silly patent (while working at Dell about 20 years ago) on a way to cause a CPU reset without external hardware (used to be done through the keyboard controller):

```
   MOV ESP,1
   PUSH EAX    ; triple fault and reset!
```

An OUTB instruction can't cause a fault on its own. My guess is you are re-enabling an interrupt, and the interrupt gets triggered while something is wrong with your stack.

Answer (score 1):

When you re-enable the PIC, are you doing it with the CPU's interrupt flag set, or cleared (ie. are you doing it sometime after a `CLI` opcode, or, sometime after an `STI` opcode)?

Assuming that the CPU's interrupt flag is enabled, your act of re-enabling the PIC allows any pending interrupts to reach the CPU: which would interrupt your code, dispatch to a vector specified by the IDT, etc.

So I expect that it's not your opcode that's directly causing the fault: rather, what's faulting is code that's run as the result of an interrupt which happens as a result of your re-enabling the PIC.

Comment: I wish that were the case, but we have code to automatically disable the flag. So I am quite sure that is not the issue.

Comment: It was disabled when your ISR was entered, but might it have been reenabled inside your ISR? Have you looked at the flag, and/or issued another CLI, just before issuing EOI?